# Changing a javascript class property from an ajax post function callback function in the class method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oop

Below is the content of my javascript file.

```
var inyavicsage = inyavicsage || {};

inyavicsage.TestClass = function () {
    this.testProperty = null;
}

inyavicsage.TestClass.prototype = {
    constructor: this,
    testMethod: function () {
        testClass = this;

        $.post('test.php', function(data){
            testClass.testProperty = data;
        });

        alert(testClass.testProperty);
    }
}

var testClass = new inyavicsage.TestClass();
testClass.testMethod();
```

I expect that the "alert(testClass.testProperty)" statement should display the content of the "data" variable assigned to "testClass.testProperty" but rather it displays "null".

What's the problem and the solution to it?

Answer (score 3):

`alert(testClass.testProperty)` displays `null` because the post request is asynchronous.

So basically you're getting the property before it will be set.
This will work:

```
$.post('test.php', function(data){
    testClass.testProperty = data;
    alert(testClass.testProperty);
});
```

Comment: Sorry @InyavicSage for the late replay, you will be able to get the data inside the function, where I put the alert function.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the asynchronous nature of javascript, the post is made and then it continues to run. when it gets to the alert it is null.

Solution is to call a function in the callback of the post